# Keep Outlook 2016 open when you click "x" to close the window

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

There are other posts on the topic of tweaks and plugins to get outlook to stay open when you click "x" to close the window.  My question is slightly simpler.  Is there some way to keep outlook open, even when you click "x" to close a window with the main program, if you also have a draft email open in a separate window.

Most programs stay open until you close the last window generate by the program.  But the default behavior on outlook is to close the entire program as soon as you close the main window (showing your inbox).

Comment: You can vote for it here: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/32337478-minimize-outlook-on-close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free product I use called [ReliefJet Quicks](https://www.reliefjet.com/Quicks/Features/QuickTweaks) that I am quite happy with. It works with my copy of Outlook 2016 x64 running on a Windows 10 x64 machine. There is an option in it that allows you to keep Outlook open when clicking the X button. You can see that in this screenshot:

[image]

There used to be some VBA and other plugin solutions, but I haven't found any that work in the current version of Outlook.

Edit: In response to your edit; yes, ReliefJet will still keep Outlook open even if you have a new email open.
Edit 2: I am fairly certain it was here on SE that I first found out about ReliefJet. If you search for it, you will find several references. Apparently, I'm not the only happy customer.

Comment: This is clearly spam.

Comment: @COMisHARD, how so?

Comment: it doesn't address my question at all and promotes a product.

Comment: What's wrong with promoting a product if it works? You asked a question; the product I mentioned in my answer provides the solution you are looking for. However, I will edit my answer to indicate it does offer a solution to your question. Sorry, for that. I assumed that my providing an answer tacitly implied that it offered a solution.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I did provide a link, and I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  Turns out its not spam ;)  I appreciate the response.

Comment: it works however it is paid product